# Create .desktop file that asks for command line options before running script

Tags: launcher

I have a script that I run from time to time which takes command line options.

I wish to create a `.desktop` file that I can run without having to open a terminal first, navigate to the folder where the script is and then run the script.

Is there a way to create a desktop launcher that when run, asks for the command line options (maybe using `zenity --entry`) and then runs the command in a terminal?

Comment: Why not prompt in the script?

Comment: I haven't created the script myself and wouldn't know how to modify it. Furthermore, finding a way to do what I asked could be useful for other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Panki, I tried modifying the script to ask for an input using zenity.

I added a line at the beginning of the script:

```
VARIABLE = $(zenity --entry --title="Title" --text="Enter text")
```

Then I used `$VARIABLE` instead of the command line input.

Then I created a .desktop file as usual pointing to the script.
It's not super neat, but it works.